# Find acceleration time for u,a,t,s

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

A car moves from point $A$ to $B$ in $t_{\text{total}}$.

$$v_i=0\ m/s\\
a= 0.65\ m/s^2\ (acceleration)\\ 
d=-0.65\ m/s^2\ (deceleration)\\ 
v_{max}  = 1 m/s\\
t_{\text{total}}=10.0\ s\\
s_{A\to B}(\text{Distance})=15.0\ m\\$$

> **Problem 1**
>
> Solve $t_{\text{acc}}$ when the car does not decelerates towards point
> $B$.
>
> In other words, how long can the car accelerate until it
> reaches the velocity that will get the car to point $B$ at
> $t_{\text{total}}$?
>
> Behaviour of the car:
>
> The car will accelerate to $v_{\text{max}}$ and then keep this velocity until it reaches point $B$.

I am aware of the fact the car will 'overshoot' point $B$ in this case.

#### Edit for problem 1 (@Botond)

$$
\text{Expressing the problem in distances:}\\
\text{We know:}\\
$$

$$
s = v_f(t_{total} - t_{acc})\\
v_f = v_i + at
$$

$$
\text{We have 2 equations}\\
s_{acc}= \frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t_{acc}\\
s_{const} = v_f(t_{total} - t_{acc})\\
$$

$$
\text{Combine the 2 equations:}\\
t_{acc} . a . (t_{total} - t_{acc}) + \frac{t_{acc}.a}{2} . t_{acc} = S_{A\to B}\\
t_{total}.t_{acc}.a.-at_{acc}^2 + \frac{1}{2}at_{acc}^2 = S_{A\to B}\\
-\frac{1}{2}at_{acc}^2+t_{total}.at_{acc}=S_{A\to B}\\
\text{Can write as:}\\
-\frac{1}{2}ax^2+Tax=S_{A\to B }\\
\text{where:}\\
x = t_{acc}\\
T = t_{total}\\
$$

$$
\text{Now with actual values:}\\
$$

$$
T = 10sec.\\
S = 15 m.\\
a = 0.65 m/s^2\\
-0.325^2+(10 * 0,65)x=S_{A\to B }\\
-0.325x^2+6,5x=S_{A\to B }\\
\text{This leaves me the quadratic problem:}\\
-0.325x^2 + 6,5x = 10\\
-0.325x^2 + 6,5x - 10 = 0\\
\text{solves}\\
x_1 = 2.6620061429465727\\
x_2 = 17.337993857053426\\
x_1 \text{seems to be the right answer, I will edit this post to prove it}
$$

> **Problem 2**
>
> Solve $t_\text{acc}$ and $t_{\text{dec}}$ when the car comes to a
> complete stop at point $B$.
>
> Behaviour of the car:
>
> The car will accelerate to $v_{\text{max}}$ and start deceleration at $t_{\text{2}}$  so it will come to a stop at  $B$.
>
> If the car can reach $v_{\text{max}}$ it will accelerate to $v_{\text{max}}$ and reach this velocity at $t_{\text{1}}$. Then at $t_{\text{2}}$ it needs to decelerate to $v=0$ so it will have $v=0$ at point $B$.
> If it can not reach $v_{\text{max}}$ then I want to calculate $t_{\text{1}}$ where we the acceleration flips to deceleration.

#### Edit for problem 2 (@Botond)

Try to express distance traveled:

Values given to solve this problem:
$$
a = 0.65 m/2^2\\
d = 0.65 m/s^2\\
v_{max} = 1.0 m/s\\
t_{total} = 10.0 s\\
s_{A\to B} = 15.0 m\\
$$

The problem states insinuates we do not know if the car will reach $v_{max}$ in the given time, or if the trajectory is even possible in the given time. This will be my first check, do we reach $v_{max}$. If we do reach $v_{max}$ we have a slightly different calculation than if we do not reach $v_{max}$.

We calculate the time it would take the car to accelerate from $v_{i} = 0$ to $v_{max} = 1.0 m/s$ and decelerate back to $v_{f} = 0$ with $a = d = 0.65m/s^2$.

$$
t_{acc} = v_{max}/a \\
t_{dec} = v_{max}/d \\
t_{ad} = t_{acc} + t_{dec} \\
$$
$$
t_{acc} = 1.0 / 0.65 \\
t_{acc} = 1.5384615385 s\\
t_{dec} = 1.0 / 0.65 \\
t_{dec} = 1.5384615385 s\\
t_{ad} = 1.5384615385 s + 1.5384615385 s\\
t_{ad} = 3.076923077 s\\
$$

Now we know the time it will take a complete acceleration and deceleration. We can calculate the displacement for $t_{ad}$. In case $a == d$ we can use $t_{ad}$. In case $a != d$ we should use $t_{acc}$ and $t_{dec}$.

For $a == d$:
$$
s = 0.5at^2\\
s_{ad} = at_{ad}^2\\
s_{ad} = 0.65 * 3.076923077^2\\
s_{ad} = 6.1538461542 m
$$

For $a != d$
$$
s = 0.5at^2\\
s_{ad} = 0.5at_{acc}^2 + 0.5at_{dec}^2\\
s_{ad} = 0.325 (3.076923077^2) + 0.325 (3.076923077^2)\\
s_{ad} = 6,1538461542 m
$$

Now we know the time it will take the car to reach $v_{max}$ and back to $v_{f} = 0$. If we compare $t_{ad}$ with $t_{total}$ we say:

If $t_{total} < t_{ad}$ the car **will not** reach $v_{max}$
If $t_{total} >= t_{ad}$ the car **will** reach $v_{max}$
For both situations applies different logic.

Situation $t_{total} >= t_{ad}$:
There are three parts in this trajectory. The acceleration part, the constant velocity part, and the deceleration part. For each part we can now calculate the displacements:
$$
s_{acc} = 0.5at^2\\
s_{acc} = 0.325(t_{acc}^2)\\
s_{acc} = 0.325(t_{acc}^2)\\
s_{acc} = 0.325(2.3668639054)\\
s_{acc} = 0,7692307693\\
$$

$$
t_{acc} = \frac{v_{const}-v_i}{a}\\
t_{dec} = \frac{v_f - v_{const}}{a}\\
t_{const} = t_{total} = t_{acc} - t_{dec}\\
$$

$$
s_{acc} = \frac{v_i+v_{const}}{2}t_{acc}\\
s_{dec} = \frac{v_{const}+v_f}{2}t_{dec}\\
s_{const} = v_{const}.t_{const}\\
$$

$$
\text{Combine the 3 distance equations:}\\
v_f(t_{const}) + \frac{v_i + v_{const}}{2}.t_{acc} + \frac{v_{const} + v_f}{2}.t_{dec} = s_{A\to B}\\
\text{Since:}\\
v_f = v_i + at\\
\text{we can rewrite to:}\\
(v_i + at)(t_{const}) + \frac{v_i + v_{const}}{2}.t_{acc} + \frac{v_{const} + v_f}{2}.t_{dec} = s_{A\to B}\\
$$

Work in progress...

Comment: Please include your attempts to solve the question

Comment: What is this $d$ term? And it's not very clear how exactly the car moves. First it accelerates ... and then what? Continues with a constant velocity? Starts decelerating?

Comment: @MattiP. $d$ is probably the deceleration, $a$ the acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 1: The car is accelerating for $t_{acc}$ time and going with the same velocity for the rest of the time: $t_{total}-t_{acc}$. How much distance will it cover during the acceleration? And what about the rest? I think you can calculate those easily. And their sum must be the $s_{A \to B}$.

For problem 2: Try to express the distance traveled, just like in the first problem.

Some useful formulas:
$$s=v_it+\frac{a}{2}t^2$$
$$s=\frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t$$
$$v_f=v_i+at$$
$$v_f=\sqrt{2as+v_i^2}$$
For the first one: We are accelerating to $v_{f}$ from $v_i=0$. It will take $$t_{acc}=\frac{v_f}{a}$$
time. In the second part of te trip, we are going with constant $v_f$ velocity for $t-t_{acc}$ time. The distance traveled during this time is
$$s=v_f(t_{total}-t_{acc})$$
So we have $2$ equations:
$$v_f(t_{total}-t_{acc})+\frac{v_f}{2}t_{acc}=s_{A \to B}$$
$$t_{acc}=\frac{v_f}{a}$$
Which implies that
$$v_f\left(t_{total}-\frac{v_f}{a}\right)+\frac{v_f}{2} \frac{v_f}{a}=s_{A \to B}$$
Or
$$t_{acc}a(t_{total}-t_{acc})+\frac{t_{acc}a}{2}t_{acc}=s_{A \to B}$$

Comment: My problem is, I do not known the acceleration time, nor the maximum velocity. I just know my initial position, target position, time it should take to get there and the acceleration. So I need to know ho long to accelerate to a velocity which is enough to reach the target exactly at the time I want it to.

Comment: @TomVos I added some useful formulas to my answer, they might help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the formulas, especially the last one helped me out. About problem 1: I do not have T_acc. That is why I can not wrap my head around it. I just know I have to accelerate to a certain (unknown) velocity, and keep this velocity until I reach point B at T_total. Thanks again though :)

Comment: @TomVos Could you solve the second problem? I added my thoughts to the first problem, please check it if you agree with it or not :)

Comment: The problem is just how you described it. Amazing how you throw those formula's back and forth! I am almost there when it comes to problem 1. It is nice the be left with only one unknown to solve, either V_f or T_acc. Now I will try solving this. My goal is to solve/calculate the solution programmatically. Let's see if I can solve this now...

Comment: I did edit my post and did add the logic I thought was necessary to solve the problem. I am left with a quadratic formule which, when solved, does not seem correct.

Comment: @TomVos Are you sure about the roots of the quadratic polynomial? $0$ is quite impossible if the constant term is not zero.

Comment: @TomVos I'm getting $x \approx 1.433$ and $x \approx -20.933$ as roots.

Comment: @TomVos And I think your equation is wrong as well. I've got $-0.325x^2+6.5x-15=0$, and $x \approx 2.662$ and $x \approx 17.338$ as the roots. And the $x \approx 2.662$ seems to be correct.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the heads up. I accidentally took a=-0.5 instead of a=-0.5 * a (-0.325). Now that I fixed that, I got the same answer. Thank you for supporting me solving this problem!

Comment: @TomVos Coule you finish the 2nd excercise?

Comment: nah.. Please look at my edits. I am completely stuck on simplifying the equation again. I have a strong feeling I am mixing things up. The hard part for me to understand here is the fact that the s_acc and s_dec have different numerators.

Comment: @TomVos Is it going with a constant speed in the second part after the acceleration for a while, or starts to decelerate immediately?

Comment: now that you mention it, there is maximum velocity. I can imagine that if the time for the complete trajectory is not enough to reach this v_{max} we get a triangle shaped motion profile. If we do reach v_{max} we will have a trapezoidal shaped motion profile. I will add the v_{max} to my post.

Comment: @TomVos I think you made a mistake. $t_{const}=t-t_{acc}-t_{dec}$. And you can also use the fact that $v_i=v_f=0$.

Comment: I see, I will change it and try to figure it out. I was away for my work so didn't had a change to look at this for a while.